# Lanza la aplicación en el celular android conectado

Tags: ionic, typescript, ionic-framework

Termine de desarrollar mi aplicación en ionic3 pero siempre estuve trabajado con el navegador, pero al necesitar utilizar ionic-native me da error y estoy tratando de ejecutarlo directamente en el móvil pero me da el siguiente error al ejecutar

```
ionic cordova run android
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 13.908 secs
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_3h27kqsye81muyru9xhrcgotr.run(C:\xampp\htdocs\nutricia\platforms\android\build.gradle:141)
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 26 in C:\Users\Deivis\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 26 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Platform 26].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.282 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Platform 26].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).

he intentado resolver el problema en los siguientes link pero no he tenido resultados

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392345/ionic-build-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-followin

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383323/cant-accept-license-agreement-android-sdk-platform-24

Les agradecería la ayuda, muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Conectas el Movil en modo Depuracion  ( debe estar activado el modo desarrollador en el movil )

utiliza los siguientes comandos

```html
// Agega la plataforma primero

ionic cordova platform add android




//construimos la app para la platadorma que agregamos

ionic cordova build android

//corremos la app en el movil

ionic cordova run android
```

Comment: Hice eso y no me funcionaba el problema estaba en que no estaba bajo la misma red. Muchas Gracias por la ayuda.